# How to add each element in two vectors with Theano?

Tags: python, theano, theano.scan

I would like to know how to add each element in two vectors with Theano?

Assume that we have two vector *vector_1* and *vecotr_2*, and we would like to construct a matrix *A*, where

> *A[i][j]* = *vector_1[i]* + *vecotr_2[j]*

I know that in numpy we can use list comprehension. But i would like to use Theano obtain the result with less time. It seems that Theano.scan() can do this job, but i really don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: I implement this code with theano at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6845486/z-lam). And numpy.add is much faster in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of broadcasting. Here is an example in NumPy, you can do the same in Theano:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x1 = np.array([1,1,9]).reshape((3,1))
>>> x2 = np.array([0,3,4]).reshape((1,3))
>>> np.add(x1, x2)
array([[ 1,  4,  5],
       [ 1,  4,  5],
       [ 9, 12, 13]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Your answer is very helpful. I decided to use numpy since it is fast enough :)